# How to target specific div and then toggle class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, I have this menu:

```js
function toggleHiddenContent(tabClass) {
    let t = document.querySelectorAll(tabClass);
    for(var i = 0; i<t.length; i++) {
        t[i].classList.toggle="visible-class";
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden-content {
    display: none;
}
.visible-class {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="main-holder" onClick="toggleHiddenContent('.main-holder')">Main one</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content One</div>

    <a class="main-holder" onClick="toggleHiddenContent('.main-holder')">Main two</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content two</div>
</div>
```

However, it toggles for all classes. I do understand what is the issue, but how would I match only the one that is clicked and not the ones that are not active (clicked)?

I need it in vanilla js

Thanks guys

Comment: You may want to avoid using HTML's `onClick` attribute as this will make your javascript obtrusive. For toggling classes you could refer to jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method as well.

Comment: Do you want to show the hidden content on clicking the `main-holder` or just want to toggle the `main-holder` class?

Comment: Also depending on the type of browsers you'll support id consider looking at [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui, I want to show hidden content

Comment: @JohnSam Check the answer below. I have toggle the class to show the content as per clicking on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```js
function toggleHiddenContent(e) {
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("visible-class") ) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.className = "hidden-content";
      
    } else {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.className = "visible-class";   
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden-content {
    display: none;
}
.visible-class {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="main-holder" onClick="toggleHiddenContent(event)">Main one</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content One</div>

    <a class="main-holder" onClick="toggleHiddenContent(event)">Main two</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just doing `e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("visible-class");` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

`classList.toggle` is a function, not an assignable property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

try this

```
function toggleHiddenContent(tabClass) {
  let t = document.querySelectorAll(tabClass);
  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    t[i].classList.toggle("visible-class");
  }
}
```

Based on your example I would suggest you a few little changes, which will improve readability, like setting a parent `<div>` (makes it easy to find parent), and removing `onClick` from HTML. check it out

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3dj0rak/)

from the answer below, I didn't know about `nextElementSibling`, which won't need you to change your HTML like I've suggested

Comment: It is, but this will still toggle all.. :)

Comment: @JohnSam which one do you need to toggle?

Comment: @CapitanFindus, I need to toggle the hidden content next to main holder that is clicked..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (and also prevent obtrusive javascript):

```js
//Get the element(s) you want to interact with and store these in an array:
let myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("main-holder");
//Loop through the array to add an event listener to every interactable element:
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (myElements[i]) {
    myElements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //Your function:
      toggleHiddenContent("visible-class", i);
    });
  }
}

function toggleHiddenContent(tabClass, target) {
  //Get the element(s) you want to manipulate (or adjust) and store these in an array:
  let targetElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-content");
  //Use the index you got from clicking on the previous element to determine which targeted element to manipulate (or adjust):
  targetElements[target].classList.toggle(tabClass);
}
```

```css
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}

.visible-class {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="main-holder">Main one</a>
  <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content One</div>

  <a class="main-holder">Main two</a>
  <div class="hidden-content">Hidden content two</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzpvewjo/)

If you need any more information, please let me know in a comment.